# error 500 with xampp for linux and joomla

Tags: joomla, xampp, http-error

Im using ubuntu and XAMPP for linux and I have a problem when I try to upload an extension greater than 500kb in Joomla, I get an "HTTP Error 500"

http://s4.postimage.org/7wgxcfveq/error500.jpg

My php.ini file is configured following the joomla recomendations:

"display_errors=Off"......

here is my error log

> [Mon Jun 06 14:12:45 2011] [notice]
>   suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper:
>   /opt/lampp/bin/suexec) [Mon Jun 06
>   14:12:45 2011] [warn] RSA server
>   certificate is a CA certificate
>   (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?) [Mon
>   Jun 06 14:12:45 2011] [warn] RSA
>   server certificate CommonName (CN)
>   `localhost' does NOT match server
>   name!? [Mon Jun 06 14:12:46 2011]
>   [notice] Digest: generating secret for
>   digest authentication ... [Mon Jun 06
>   14:12:46 2011] [notice] Digest: done
>   [Mon Jun 06 14:12:47 2011] [warn] RSA
>   server certificate is a CA certificate
>   (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?) [Mon
>   Jun 06 14:12:47 2011] [warn] RSA
>   server certificate CommonName (CN)`
>   localhost' does NOT match server
>   name!? [Mon Jun 06 14:12:48 2011]
>   [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) DAV/2
>   mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/1.0.0c
>   PHP/5.3.5 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1
>   mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured
>   -- resuming normal operations [Mon Jun 06 14:15:34 2011] [error] [client
>   192.168.56.1] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds
>   exceeded in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/csu/libraries/joomla/filesystem/archive/tar.php
>   on line 154, referer:
>   http://192.168.56.101/csu/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=install

Comment: im using XAMPP 1.74 and ubuntu 10

Comment: All that the return code 500 means is that there was a server error.  Most likely, more relevant messages are being placed in error.log, or other equivalent file.  They would be extremely useful for attempting to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP Fatal error is "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded".

You could try increasing this by altering the max_execution_time in the php.ini file or create a .htaccess file containing..

```
php_value max_execution_time 60
```

Should the installation of an extension take longer than 30 seconds? 
There might be a script issue, such as an endless loop, that's causing problems.